# How to align the subviews next to the leading edge of widget, but not to the background image in ZStack?

Tags: swiftui, zstack

The image is larger than the widget frame size, and its proportion is 16:10.

The problem is, for subviews in `ZStack` when under small widget size, both the image(as background) and views above image, are not aligned to the widget itself, but exceed, only half appears.

Is there a way to position all subviews along **the widget itself** leading edge?

Below is the pic & code:

```
   var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Image("bkgImage")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        
        if self.widgetFamily == .systemSmall {
            SmallWidgetView()
                .padding(.leading, 12)

        } else if self.widgetFamily == .systemMedium {
            mediumView
                .padding(.leading, 12)
                .padding(.trailing, 12)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could either:

- Reformat your image
- Change your ZStack into an H/VStack, get your widgets out of there and into a parent ZStack like this:

  ZStack{
  VStack{
  Image()
  }
  SmallWidgetView()
  }